# I am unable to connect to bluetooth after updating my iOS to 15.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, eaaccessory

I can able to list all the available bluetooth devices, but when selected I got this

```
error: "Error Domain=EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)""
```

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:nil completion:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error :%@", error);
    } else {
       // Do something
    }
}];
```

Please let me know, if anyone has some thoughts.

Comment: That error is EABluetoothAccessoryPickerResultNotFound. My expectation would be a bug on the firmware side, though if this is a regression from 14 or 15 to 15.1, I would open a feedback with Apple, or use a DTS if it's urgent.

Comment: I am sure that it is definitely due to iOS 15.1 update. Yes, I need to use DTS. Thanks for your inputs. @RobNapier.

Comment: I am checking with the beta versions, this issue still exists in iOS 15.2(19C5026i).

Answer (score 1):

I did emailed to Apple about this issue, and they agreed that it an iOS issue and also said that they dont any workaround for it.

So my guess is we need to wait for the official release which is very bad.

Below is the response from Apple

*From: Apple Developer Technical Support dts@apple.com*

*Subject: Re: DTS Auto-Ack - I am unable to connect to bluetooth after updating my iOS to 15.1.*

*Follow-up: 784883575*

*Hello Vishwanath Kota,*

*Thanks for filing a Feedback Assistant report and attaching the sysdiagnose.*

*Although DTS is typically not able to provide any information about a specific Feedback Assistant report, I can say that it's normal for a Feedback Assistant report to be 'open' while an issue in iOS is being investigated.  You should therefore expect the report's status to remain 'open' until this investigation is complete.*

*As my previous email also mentioned, it is normal and expected (unless additional information is required) that the submitter of a Feedback Assistant report will not receive a response to their submission.  If additinonal information isn't required to investigate your report you should therefore not expect to receive a response to your submission.*

*In summary, the issue you've encountered appears to be a bug in iOS.  It also appears that a work around is not possible.*

*Best regards,*
*Craig*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).